# C# : any exception for namespaces not found?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Does it exist a particular exception raised when the namespace declared inside a C# 'using' statement doesn't exist?

I'd like to have a code structure like this:

```cs
public class TestClass {
    public bool CheckNamespace() {
        try
        {
            using Not.Existing.CsNamespace;
            return true;
        }
        catch( ???Exception e )
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking about this since I would like to have a Cs script able to check if a given namespace exists or not. I'm working with Unity (maybe it exists another secret method or trick which is better than this idea).

Thank you! ;)

Hi guys,

Does it exist a particular exception raised when the namespace declared inside a C# 'using' statement doesn't exist?

I'd like to have a code structure like this:

```cs
public class TestClass {
    public bool CheckNamespace() {
        try
        {
            using Not.Existing.CsNamespace;
            return true;
        }
        catch( ???Exception e )
        {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking about this since I would like to have a Cs script able to check if a given namespace exists or not. I'm working with Unity (maybe it exists another secret method or trick which is better than this idea).

Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the System.Reflection library and the code below to check if a certain namespace exists in your project. The method returns true if the namespace is found and false if the namespace was not found.

```
using System.Reflection;
public bool NameSpaceExists(string namespace){
//loop through the assemblies and check the namespace names against the name of our namespace
  foreach (Assembly assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            foreach (Type type in assembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.Namespace == namespace)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome and anytime.

Comment: @Charlieface, Yeah that is a fine idea. That would make the code more efficient in terms of execution time.